# Flutter App working debug mode, in release app not working

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, filepicker

When i run **flutter run --release -v** this command below error came

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.lifecycle.b implemented by class
com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver' appears in
/data/app/app.projects.xxx.mobile-1/base.apk)
```

My Gradle is
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'   //4.0.1 //3.3.2 //3.5.3 //3.4.2

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

Go to `build.gradle` file at `android/gradle` and downgrade to version 3.6.2 like shown below,

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
```

Answer taken from this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479).

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue, its related to gradle 4+ version i guess, i was able to resolve this by following below steps.

Add bellow line to app/proguard-rules.pro (if file not present create one.)

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
```

Error from logcat, it was only having issue in release build. The emulator was working fine. -

```
03-12 07:41:32.281 22847 22847 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.lifecycle.b implemented by class com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver' appears in base.apk)
```

Related Discussion/Issue can be found here -https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your grade classpath and distribution url to latest version.
also filepicker to latext version in pubspec.yaml

check if it works... if not then open `android/gradle.properties` and see if the following lines are there or not if not then add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

check if following are there in your `android/app/build.gradle` or not

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
multiDexEnabled true
```

then `flutter clean`

then instead of directly running `flutter run --release -v` use the following its not related to your issue but it will cause another you will get something missingFile exception.

```
flutter build apk --debug
then flutter build apk --profile;
then flutter build apk --release;
```